# how can i sum values in a dictionary of dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1 = [{'d2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd': 0'}}]
```

how can I sum values of a dictionary in a dictionary? i have tried many times

Comment: Please post your attempts so people can help you correct them. It's always good to start from somewhere, other than just requesting for the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function that checks the type of the input

```
d1 = [{'d2': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c':3, 'd': 0}}]

def sumThis(inp):
    
    if type(inp) == int: return inp

    elif type(inp) == dict:
        ret = 0
        for k,v in inp.items():
            ret += sumThis(v)
        return ret
    
    elif type(inp) == list:
        ret = 0
        for v in inp: ret += sumThis(v)
        return ret
    
    else: return 0


print(sumThis (d1))
```

```
6
```

PS: This will handle any number of `dict` nesting

Comment: @juna because you are trying to input a list of dict. This only works for dict of dict, as mentioned din the title of the question

Comment: @juna I have updated it for `list` as well